# Using overlapping patterns in GtkSourceView

Tags: xml, gtksourceview

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify overlapping patterns in a GtkSourceView 3 XML language file? For example, in the text below, is there a way to highlight "some text..." between *foo* and *bar* in one color and "some more text..." between *bar* and *baz* in another color? The problem here is that *bar* is the end of one context and also the start of another, which means that the *bar-baz* context will never apply.

```
foo
some text...
bar
some more text...
baz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The *bar* section can be included in the *foo* section:

```
<context id="bar" style-ref="bar" style-inside="true" extend-parent="false">
   <start>^bar\b</start>
</context>

<context id="foo" style-ref="foo" style-inside="true">
   <start>^foo\b</start>
   <end>^baz\b</end>
   <include>
      <context ref="bar"/>
   </include>
</context>
```